# VB.net - Adding vertical line to line graph

Tags: vb.net, graph

I have a graph with data coming from a text box input. Is there a way to add a vertical line at a given point on the X-Axis?

I have looked at StripLines but I can't get them at a specific point in time. I have also looked at combining a column chart with a bar chart but can't seem to get the desired effect.

I am using the standard Chart control with the Chart Type being drawn as a line.

Thanks,
John

Comment: just invert from gorizontal to vertical using Y axis instead of X https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59514030-45cc-426a-937e-e1dff4ede2e1/mschart-how-to-add-a-parallel-line-to-x-axis-c-sharp?forum=MSWinWebChart

Comment: That has worked, thanks for the link!

Comment: No problem i'll write an answer so you can validate it if you want

Comment: If you can convert your comment to an answer, I can accept it?